# How to write a static method that returns a subclass instance

Tags: typescript, abstract-class, subclass, static-methods

I'm trying to create an abstract class `Enum`, which has a bunch of static methods that return instances of the class they were called on. My problem is that I can't figure out how to type these methods correctly.

Essentially, I want TypeScript to understand that `EnumSubclass.getFirstInstance()` returns a `EnumSubclass` instance, and not an `Enum` instance.

Here is my best attempt so far:

```js
type InstanceOf<T> = T extends { prototype: infer R } ? R : never

const instances = {}

abstract class Enum {
    protected constructor(
        public readonly name: string,
    ){
        instances[name] = this
    }

    public static getInstances<T extends typeof Enum>(this: T): InstanceOf<T>[] {
        return Object.values(instances)
    }

    public static getFirstInstance<T extends typeof Enum>(this: T): InstanceOf<T> {
        // No warning here, TypeScript understands that this.getInstances exists
        return this.getInstances()[0]
    }
}


class Demo extends Enum {
    public static readonly FOO = new Demo('foo', true)

    protected constructor(
        name: string,
        public readonly bar: boolean,
    ){
        super(name)
    }
}

// The 'this' context of type 'typeof Demo' is not assignable to method's 'this' of type 'typeof Enum'.
//   Types of construct signatures are incompatible.
//     Type 'new (name: string, bar: boolean) => Demo' is not assignable to type 'abstract new (name: string) => Enum'.ts(2684)
const x: Demo = Demo.getFirstInstance()
```

Apparently TypeScript has a problem with the fact that the constructor of `Demo` has a different signature than the constructor of `Enum`, even though `Enum` never even calls the constructor - it returns instances that already exist.

How can I convince TypeScript that this is not an error?

P.S.: Ideally, I would like to:

1. Keep the constructors `protected` and not make them `public`
2. Have correct typing inside the implementation of `Enum` (for example, there shouldn't be a warning at `this.getInstances()`)

Comment: FYI, I belive your `InstanceOf` type is the same as the built in type of `InstanceType` https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#instancetypetype. I'd bet the type Typescript provides is a bit more robust.

Comment: @AlexWayne Interestingly, it's different for some reason. Using `InstanceType`, I get `Cannot assign a 'protected' constructor type to a 'public' constructor type.(2344)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is possible, as long as you don't care about the constructor.

First, define these helper types:

```
type InstanceOf<T> = T extends { prototype: infer R } ? R : never
type IgnoreConstructor<T> = Pick<T, keyof T> & {name: string}

// Replace `Enum` with your base class
type EnumSubclass = IgnoreConstructor<typeof Enum>
```

Then write your static methods like this:

```
static myFunc<T extends EnumSubclass>(this: T): InstanceOf<T>
```

[Proof that it works.](https://tsplay.dev/NrX5VW)

Answer (score 2):

That's long awaited feature that has yet to be implemented. [#5863](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/5863)

So not possible at the moment.

Comment: Well, this is awkward, because I think I found a solution? If I replace `this: T` with `this: Pick<T, keyof T>`, the warning disappears. I guess I have to consider myself lucky that I never call the constructor?

Comment: @Aran-Fey but then [the return type is `Enum`, not `Demo`](https://tsplay.dev/mM1YZm).

Comment: @AlexWayne Ah, shoot, you're right. That's what I get for not including that in my MRE.